# Will the parents be rewarded even if they have no significant role in making of one of their sons a memorizer of the Qur'an?

Tags: quran, reading-quran, reward, quran-memorization

What if I concealed the fact from my parents that I'm memorizing the Holy Qur'an! and simply because of that they never insisted me to memories the Holy Qur'an or never they sent me to any Qur’an learning institutions. Will they be rewarded in the day of judgement by the rewards that Allah will give the parents of a Memorizer of Qur'an?

Comment: This sounds like a question you should ask Allah on the Day of Judgement, not the internet.

Comment: Sounds like you don’t have any answer for that and you've just commented what has pop into your head!!!  This is a legal question which can be answered by any knowledgeable person of aahadith.